# Removing new lines/spaces from beginning and end of string Java

Tags: java, regex, replace, newline

I have a problem - I can't seem to be able to remove the new lines/spaces from the beginning/end of a string. I use `\s` in the beginning and end of the regex and even use `.trim()` after I get the string, but to no avail.

```
public void extractInfo(String mydata) {

    // regex to extract the user name
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("user:\\s*(.*)\\s+branch");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
    // regex to extract the branch name
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("branch:\\s*(.*)\\s+changed");
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(mydata);
    // regex to extract the comment and write it in a variable
    comment = mydata.replaceAll("(?s)\\s.*java;[0-9,.]+|.*java;NONE\\s", "");

    // put the author name in a variable
    matcher.find();
    author = matcher.group(1).toString();

    // put the branch name in a variable
    matcher2.find();
    branch = matcher2.group(1).toString();

    author.trim();
    comment.trim();
    branch.trim();
}
```

This is what I use to extract the info.

This is the output I get (lines kept), after I append the extracted information using StringBuilder:

```
git log --all -100 --before="2013-03-11" --branches=HEAD
--author="\(cholakov\)" --grep="^[#]*[0]*23922:[ ]*user:
```

> Fixed the message for defaulted bonds `" --pretty="%H - %s ; %ad"`

**The new line after `user:` is what causes the whole command to fail when I try to execute it in cmd, that's what I need fixed.**

And this is my input (can't seem to be able to keep the formatting, DataObjectParser.java;1.94 is on a new line and there is no line skipped between each line):

> user: cholakov
>
> branch: HEAD
>
> changed files:
> DataObjectParser.java;1.94
>
> Fixed the message for defaulted bonds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can completely remove the `.trim()` in the end if you change your regex a bit:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("user:\\s*(.*?)\\s+branch");

Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("branch:\\s*(.*?)\\s+changed");

comment = mydata.replaceAll("(?s)\\s*.*java;(?:[0-9,.]+|NONE)\\s*", "");
```

I tweaked your regex a little in each; namely made some `(.*)` into `(.*?)` so that you can remove all the trailing spaces and simplified your replace comment a bit. Try to see if that solves your issues ^^

EDIT:

Try running one last replace on the comment:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("^\\s*|\\s*$", "");
```

Comment: I only added the `.trim()`, because I was running out of other ideas, I'll try that now and see what happens.

Comment: Sadly, there's still a new line before and after `Fixed the message for defaulted bonds` (which is the comment).

Comment: @Schadenfreude Okay, I'm not quite sure what's the issue, but I added one more replace. Add it just after the first replace. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: That worked! Can I use the same regex on the other 2 patterns just to be safe?

Answer (score 2):

```
author.trim();
```

is a no-op since `String` is an immutable class. Use

```
author = author.trim();
```

Comment: Did that, and the result is the same, I guess the symbols that add a new line are somehow different and the `.trim()` doesn't remove them.

Answer (score 2):

calling author.trim RETURNS a new String, but it does not replace the one you call it from.

Answer (score 2):

The `trim` function returns **a copy of the string**, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted. You should do this instead:

```
author  = author.trim();
comment = comment.trim();
branch  = branch.trim();
```

Comment: Did that, and the result is the same, I guess the symbols that add a new line are somehow different and the `.trim()` doesn't remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try to run this stuff :

```
public class ReadFile {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "\n     Java     ";
    System.out.println(line.trim());        
 }
}
```